# finding memory leaks from leak suspect in android

Tags: android, memory-profiling

I am new for profiling. For my android application i am using eclipse mat tool to detect memory leaks. On opening .hprof file in eclipse mat tool  it says three suspects have been found. for example:
problem suspect1 : 2,341 instances of "java.lang.Class", loaded by "" occupy 8,02,520 (30.89%) bytes.

i have not done profiling before how to find where is the memory leak and how to fix it. I have googled a lot , explanation was present until finding the leak suspect using mat.please provide suggestion or link for tracing the memory leak in code.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk. Use mat analyzer. check the last part of the video

Comment: thank u ll check it out